# Given $F = (y^2cos(xy^2) - 3, 2xycos(xy^2) - 5)$, $u(0,0) =1 $ , Compute $u(2,0)$

Tags: calculus

Given $F = (y^2cos(xy^2) - 3, 2xycos(xy^2) - 5)$, and also $P'_y = Q'_x$, $u(0,0) =1 $ (potential function)

Compute $u(2,0)$ , which is $-5$.

What can I conclude from the fact that $u(0,0) = 1$? how can I use it to get more details? I believe $u(x,y) = (P(x,y),Q(x,y)$ maybe?

Comment: I solved this. We need to use newton Laybnitz. and use $dy = 0$, $ 0 \le x \le 2$ and compute the definite integral which is $-6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F(x,y)=\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$ for $u(x,y)=\sin(xy^2)-3x-5y+c$ and $u(0,0)=1$, then $c=1$.

Therefore $u(2,0)=\sin(0)-3(2)-5(0)+1=-5$